# Подсчет ветвей до заданной вершины С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Я написал функцию подсчета ветвей - `branches(TNode*&, int)`. Работает почти исправно, но если ввести несуществующую вершину, то выдает просто значение для места где бы она должна была располагаться, а нужно вывести, например, `-1`. Пытался писать различные условия, ничего не выходит, помогите.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

struct TNode {
    int data;
    TNode* left;
    TNode* right;
};

void add(TNode *&tr, int d) {

    if (tr == NULL) {
        tr = new TNode;
        tr->data = d;
        tr->left = tr->right = 0;
    }

    if (d < tr->data)
        add(tr->left, d);
    if (d > tr->data)
        add(tr->right, d);

}

int branches(TNode *&tr, int n) {
    int count = 0, cht = -1;
    if (tr == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (tr->data == n)
        return count;

    return ++count + branches(((tr->data > n) ? tr->left : tr->right), n);

}

int depth_path(TNode *&tr) {

    if (!tr)
        cout << "\nДерева не существует\n";

    if (tr->left == 0 && tr->right == 0) 
        return -1;

    return 1 + depth_path(tr->left);

}

void tree_print(const TNode* tr) {
    if (tr == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        tree_print(tr->left);
        cout << tr->data << ' ';
        tree_print(tr->right);
    }
}

void input_data(TNode *&tr, int dt) {
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов: \n"; cin >> n;

    while (n--) {
        cout << "Введите элемент: "; cin >> dt;
        add(tr, dt);
    }
}

void del(TNode *&tr) {
    if (tr != NULL) {
        del(tr->left);
        del(tr->right);
        delete tr;
        tr = NULL;
    }
}

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    TNode* tree;
    int data = 0, temp = 0, n = 0; // n - для подсчета ветвей, темп - для хранения ветвей
    tree = NULL;

    input_data(tree, data);

    cout << endl;
    tree_print(tree);

    cout << "\nКакую цифру хотите найти: "; cin >> n;
    temp = branches(tree, n);


    cout << "\nГубилна: " << depth_path(tree);

    cout << "\nКоличество ветвей: " << temp << "\n";
    del(tree);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, проверка

```
if (tr == NULL)
    return 0;
```

показывает, что нужного узла нет, и пора возвращать -1. Так? Ну так давайте и будем возвращать эту -1:

```
int branches(TNode *tr, int n) {
    int count = 0, cht = -1;
    if (tr == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (tr->data == n)
        return count;

    int br = branches(((tr->data > n) ? tr->left : tr->right), n);
    if (br == -1) return -1;
    return ++count + br;

}
```

(Не компилировал, просто показываю идею).
Еще один вариант - через генерацию исключения, но стоит ли?

Comment: Так из-за рекурсии нет гарантии, что запуск вернет -1, так как алгоритм пройдет до места, где должен быть результат и что-то насчитает по пути

Comment: @TimurYalimov Что бы он ни насчитал по пути - `-1` возвращается без изменений до начала рекурсии.

Comment: Harry, ваш способ с генерацией исключения работает хорошо. Там где у меня проверка, она не срабатывала, пока еще не разобрался почему. А почему стоит ли? Можно сделать другим способом?

Comment: Я свое решение привел. Если оно не устраивает - ищите другое. Искать решение, которое было бы не просто решением, но еще и обязательно таким, а не другим - выходит за рамки моего понимания, так сказать, волонтерства на этом сайте :)